# Batch insert a group of elements into a sorted list and get their indices

Tags: algorithms, optimization, sorting

I'm working on an update process which inserts items into a sorted list, and processes those items' indices in the sorted list.

To help me with this, I created a sorted list with an "insert" method which returns the index of the new element in the list. For example, given a list of `[1, 3, 5]`, then `insert(4)` will change the list to `[1, 3, 4, 5]` and return `2` (0-indexed). I then process the result with `process(2)`.

Currently, when I need to do multiple updates, I do something like

```
for el in elements
   index = list.insert(el)
   beginUpdates()
   process(index)
   endUpdates()
```

In want to optimise update time by processing multiple indices in a single update. Of course, the following would be incorrect:

```
indices = []
for el in elements
   indices.append(list.insert(el))
beginUpdates()
for index in indices
   process(index)
endUpdates()
```

because each insert could invalidate a previously-calculated index. For example:

```
list = [1, 3, 5]
index1 = list.insert(4) // index of 4: 2
index2 = list.insert(2) // index of 4: 3
```

Now, if I `process(index1)`, it will process the wrong index.

So I think that, in the same way that I can batch-process indices, I should have a method to batch-insert elements and get their correct indices. Something that will allow me to do

```
indices = list.batchInsert(elements)
beginUpdates()
for index in indices
   process(index)
endUpdates()
```

Is there an algorithm that can elegantly do this?

Comment: Wouldn't this problem go away if your `process()` method took the actual object as a parameter rather than an index into a list?

Comment: `process` doesn't care about the object, just the index. The real-world context is an iOS collection view update, where I tell a controller that the data source changed, and which items are new. It then queries the data source for the data at the indices I provided.

Comment: Bummer.  I don't suppose you have a `list.getIndexOf(element)` function?

Comment: I do (I'm working in Swift) (added that to fill out the characters, haha)

Comment: Sometimes what I do is the very simple: after each insertion, increment each index I  have so far if it is >= the latest insertion index.

Comment: That could definitely work, and has is better than my solution because it will return the insertion indices in the order corresponding to the input. If you write it up as an answer, I'll accept :)

Answer (score 1):

OK, so after some thinking, my colleagues and I came up with this:

`func insertBatch(elements: [Element]) -> [Int] {
   let results: [Int] = []
   let sortedElements = elements.sort()
   for el in sortedElements {
      let i = insert(el)
      results.append(i)
   }
   return results
}`

(Excuse the Swift :)
The idea is that, since the elements to be inserted are already sorted, no specific insertion will invalidate any previously-obtained index, because they're necessarily inserted *after* the previous ones.

For additional optimisation, I could write an `insert(minIndex: Int)` function that won't try to insert the new item before `minIndex`, and then pass it the previous result.

Would still like to wait and see if there's a smarter solution.

Comment: This is clever, but the return indices don't correspond to the unsorted input.  (This can be fixed, of course..)

Comment: True. In my use case, it just so happens that I don't mind the order of the return indices, but I didn't state that in the question, so this answer isn't 100% correct.